# Implement graph to call and display data from rails database.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering is it possible to implement a graph into rails application that can call an display information from a database (.rb). If so what, what is the best possible solution to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to rephrase your question and answer it in two parts.

Part 1. What do you recommend as a good charting/graphing package for a web application?

Lots of options out there, but, hands down, I prefer [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com).

Part 2. How do I integrate Highcharts with my Rails application?

See the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts) on the topic.